# IE and FF not validating HTML5 select in Angular 2

Tags: angular, html, angular2-forms

I am facing an issue with the HTML5 select element in Angular 2.

Form button remains disable even I filled all the required fields in IE and FF, but Everything works fine in Chrome.

Here is my code.

```
<form role="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #addAddressForm="ngForm">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Address Type*</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="AddressType" [disabled]="isVendorMainAddress(model.AddressType) || viewMode" [(ngModel)]="model.AddressType" ngControl="addressType" #addressType="ngForm" placeholder="Select State" required>
        <option *ngFor="#t of addressTypeList" value="{{t.cboEntry}}">{{t.cboEntry}}</option>

      </select>
      <div [hidden]="addressType.valid || addressType.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
        Address Type Is Required
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Address *</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Address" [(ngModel)]="model.Line1" [disabled]="viewMode" placeholder="Enter Address" ngControl="line1" #line1="ngForm" maxlength="64" required>
      <div [hidden]="line1.valid || line1.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
        Address Is Required
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="button-container fr mR15">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!addAddressForm.form.valid || viewMode">Save</button>
    <button type="button" (click)="ResetForm()" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I observed by inspecting select elements from the browser that in Chrome, Angular Adds 'ng-dirty' and 'ng-valid' class after I made some change on the select but FF and IE does not add 'ng-dirty' and 'ng-valid' and always displays 'ng-invalid' class even after I provide the valid data.

Comment: Probably https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6573

Comment: Thanks but I don't have binding issues with select.